# Empty value is giving wrong Value after being mapped

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-data-integrator

I have Three Tables all of them have a column called `RECORD_TYPE` which is present as empty records in the Source file.

Table 1:

```
|RECORD_TYPE|
----------
|('null')   |
```

Table 2:

```
|RECORD_TYPE|
----------
|""         |
```

Table 3 :

```
|RECORD_TYPE|
 ----------
|""         |
```

The Column mapped has the same `datatype` throughout the three tables i.e. `VARCHAR2(255)`

Table 1 shows correct result --> `('null')` but the other two are giving empty inverted commas.

DDL for Table 1 :

```
      CREATE TABLE "ODSSTAGE"."INXN_LA_RENEWAL_STG" 
       (    col1,
            col2,
            .
            .
    
        "RECORD_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) 
       )
```

DDL for Table 2 :

```
  CREATE TABLE "ODSSTAGE"."INXN_LA_TERMINATION_STG" 
   (    col1,
       col2,
        .
        .
        .



    "RECORD_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)  
   )
```

DDL for Table 3 :

```
      CREATE TABLE "ODSSTAGE"."INXN_LA_NEW_STG" 
       (    col1,
            col2,
            ..
            ..
            ..
        "RECORD_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) 
       )
```

> Source are same for all three

Please keep in mind : the `""` is something the record is showing as empty but when i copy paste the record in notepad or somewhere is else i am getting ""

Comment: You have this tagged as if it's an Oracle database question. But you show empty values as empty strings enclosed in double-quotes (or at least that's what you seem to be wanting to show). In Oracle, strings are enclosed in single-quotes. Please clarify.

Comment: I am getting records  as "" in Oracle

Comment: ... Perhaps someone tried to enter a two-character string `""` (consisting of two double-quotes), thinking that's an empty string? It is not; this might answer your question.

Comment: actually the record is showing as empty but when i copy paste the record in notepad or somewhere is else i am getting ""

Comment: What you write doesn't make sense more generally. What is the word `null`, enclosed in single quotes, and further enclosed in parentheses? Is that a value in your field, which you can read by querying the table? Is that a value that someone or something tried to insert in the table, thinking it means `null`?

Comment: What do you get if you use `SELECT DUMP(record_type) FROM ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_RENEWAL_STG` or `SELECT DUMP(record_type) FROM ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_NEW_STG`?

Comment: OK - I see your reply about Notepad. You did not mention that anywhere in your question. Notepad may add the double-quotes to indicate empty string - why are you asking it as an Oracle question and not even mention Notepad from the outset? Done with this - good luck.

Comment: @MT0 just plain NULL and for second i get Typ=1 Len=1: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > What do you get if you use `SELECT DUMP(record_type) FROM ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_RENEWAL_STG` or `SELECT DUMP(record_type) FROM ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_NEW_STG`?
>
> just plain `NULL` and for second I get `Typ=1 Len=1: 13`

You do not have a `NULL` (empty) value in the `ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_NEW_STG` table you have a single carriage return (ASCII 13) character.

You can find those rows using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_NEW_STG
WHERE  record_type = CHR(13);
```

Or update them to a `NULL` value using:

```
UPDATE ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_NEW_STG
SET   record_type = NULL
WHERE record_type = CHR(13);
```

Comment: so this means the source file doesnt have null but an ascii character

Comment: @KKU Pass, you have not shared any source files that contain `INSERT` statements. But you are looking for the difference between `INSERT INTO ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_NEW_STG ( record_type ) VALUES ( NULL );` and `INSERT INTO ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_NEW_STG ( record_type ) VALUES ( CHR(13) );` or `INSERT INTO ODSSTAGE.INXN_LA_NEW_STG ( record_type ) VALUES ( '
' );` (yes, there is a carriage return character between the `''`)

Comment: The records type has nothing but empty values in source file